# how do I export symbols in a ".bc" library (ie: .a suffix from the emar archiver builder ) to javascript?

Tags: c++, emscripten

I have an emscripten C++ build where I create several ".a" libraries in sub builds using the emar utility.  In a couple of the libraries I have some

```
extern "C" {
   void funcToExportToJavascript(int arg) {
       ...
   }
}
```

declarations.

I "link" all the objects and the libXXX.a libs into the final module .wasm + .html + .js using emcc and also pass it an exports.txt files containing the symbols I desire to export from the libraries.

emcc does not find the "exported symbols" in the libraries.  If I don't export symbols from the libraries the "link/optimize" is successful and all the C++ code gets all of it's symbols from the libraries and everything runs as expected. Symbols "exported" from the "object" files passed into the final link contained in the final individual object files are all found.

Is my only recourse to to extract all the object modules from the libraries into a temp area and add then add them to the final link individually ? Is there a way to use "emcc" to create a library with exported symbols ?

Will that cause code bloat if only a few symbols in the libraries are actually used and they are not all provided as LLVM '.bc' bitcode ?

Answer (score 1):

Well maybe this question isn't to swift as I hadn't explored all the angles.  But someone else might have the same propblem.

BUT it actually DOES work!

BUT my gotcha was you can't specify more than one exports list file for emcc - apparently only the last one specified takes.  It does so silently, no error report and no mention in the docs that one can't do it more than once.

After I consolidated all the exports into one file it all worked as desired.

Comment: If you haven't, it would be helpful to report that to the Emscripten tracker.